# Using bigscience bloom model for chat bot

Tags: python, api, discord.py, huggingface-transformers

I want to know if it is possible to use bigscience/bloom-1b7 model as a text generator for my discord.py bot just like how they used gpt-neo here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_uFjdbTthE&ab_channel=SalvatoreLaPorta

And if it is possible, where can I find tutorials, libraries, and examples on how to send and receive messages using bloom(preferably beginner friendly)

I tried looking for tutorials on youtube on how to use bloom's API and/or transformers to receive and send messages but I can't find any. I am new to API so I still don't know where I can find this kind of information.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, there's no exact tutorial for it(sorry for the wrong phrasing English is not my first language), so I am looking for instructions on how to learn it step by step just like what you said, but I don't know where to look or what to search specifically for libraries of API models like this and not just some random generators and I think huggingface site does not also have what i am looking for. That is why I don't know if it is even possible or not

Comment: Well if it's possible to generate text via the `bigscience/bloom-1b7` model, then what you're doing is possible. You maybe could try asking a new question just specifically about each step that you're not sure of - asking about the whole thing at once is just too broad. If you don't know how to start generating text with that model, just ask about/research that, specifically.

Comment: Okay, thank you at least now I know that it is possible. I'll post another question if I still can't find anything in a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Bloom is based on the Megatron GPT model which is also designed to be a "causal" language model. Causal here means that the text the model generates is based on the sequence of words that preceded it (this is called "unidirectional").

So depending on what you want your chatbot to say, you may want to do some fine-tuning to the model on your own dataset. You can also pre-prompt the model with text to give it context. Example pre-prompt: "I am a discord chatbot, how can I help?"

Once you have the output text of your model, you can use the Discord API to feed it into your discord chatbot.

Keep in mind, your chatbot may be unpredictable and likely won't say the same thing every time. If you want a more predictable chatbot that can dynamically choose from a pre-set number of phrases, you can look into tutorials like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HifpykuTI4